# Deploying existing python package to Azure function succesfull, but not recognized

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, dynatrace

Dynatrace offers a [default package](https://github.com/dynatrace-oss/dynatrace-azure-log-forwarder/releases/latest/download/dynatrace-azure-log-forwarder.zip) (in python) which enables forwarding logs from an eventhub to their platform.
[Here is their documentation about it.](https://docs.dynatrace.com/docs/setup-and-configuration/setup-on-cloud-platforms/microsoft-azure-services/azure-integrations/set-up-log-forwarder-azure)

I am using an existing python azure function in which I want to deploy it to using Azure DevOps yaml pipeline.

```
Write-Host 'Downloading'
wget "${{ parameters.logForwarderPackageUrl }}" -O "log-forwarder.zip"

Write-Host 'Deploying'
az webapp deployment source config-zip `
  --resource-group "${{ parameters.resourceGroup }}" `
  --name "logforwarder-dev" `
  --src "log-forwarder.zip"
```

The azure function has a configuration setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` set to `true`.

I also have tried `az functionapp deployment...` but this sets the `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `false` for some reason.

The problem is that deployment is successful but somehow the package isn't running.
This is the output of the script:

```
WARNING: Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
WARNING: Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
WARNING: Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
```

Does anyone know what I have been missing or what I have to check to see why the python script isn't running/deploying?

[image]

For what I can tell, all essential files are deployed.

[image]

[image]

I do not have enough experience with Python to see my issue. Please help.

Comment: Try to set these values in `Configuration` of function app and redeploy.
ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD: true, SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT: true, AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags: EnableWorkerIndexing

Comment: Ik might figured out the problem. Ik has to do with that the bicep-script not setting the proper phyton runtime.
In the configuration - general settings, the python version field was empty.
In Bicep I did set the pythonVersion in siteConfig to 3.11 but that didn't work.
I now set linuxFxVersion to 'Python|3.11' which seems to work better.
I also tried to set ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD to true earlier, but that only seems to worsen the problem as that the deployment failed entirly.

Comment: Can you share your bicep script please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by having the correct runtime configured in the function app.

I previously set the `pythonVersion` in siteConfig to `3.11` but that didn't work.
Now I use `linuxFxVersion` `Python|3.11` which does seem to work.

This is the bicep I am now using.

```
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: '${name}-${environmentDTAP}'
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: serverFarmId
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess: use32BitWorkerProcess
      alwaysOn: alwaysOn
      linuxFxVersion: 'Python|3.11'
      appSettings: [
          {
            name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
            value: blobStorageConnectionString
          }
          {
            name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
            value: '~4'
          }
          {
            name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
            value: 'python'
          }
          {
            name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
            value: appInsights.outputs.instrumentationKey
          }
          {
            name: 'DYNATRACE_URL'
            value: dynatraceLogForwarderApiUrl
          }
          {
            name: 'DYNATRACE_ACCESS_KEY'
            value: dynatraceLogForwarderApiKey
          }
          {
            name: 'EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING'
            value: eventHub.outputs.listenConnectionString
          }
          {
            name: 'EVENTHUB_NAME'
            value: eventHub.outputs.eventHubName
          }
          {
            name: 'SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT'
            value: 'true'
          }
          {
            name: 'REQUIRE_VALID_CERTIFICATE'
            value: 'false'
          }
          {
            name: 'SELF_MONITORING_ENABLED'
            value: 'false'
          }
          {
            name: 'RESOURCE_ID'
            value: '${name}-${environmentDTAP}'
          }
          {
            name: 'REGION'
            value: location
          }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```